# how to replace jdbctemplate with jpa in jobrepository of springbatch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

hi actually springbatch jobrepository uses jdbctemplate for the CRUD operations of springbatch metadata
and my requirement is to replace jdbctemplate with jpa and do the crud operations...
the actual configuration of springbatch job repository is as follows...

can anyone kindly help regarding this issue...i searched alot but got nothing......

```
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/test" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />

</bean>

<!-- create job-meta tables automatically -->
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="jobRepository-dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql" />
    <jdbc:script location="classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jobRepository-dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository-transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    lazy-init="true">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jobRepository-dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean" >
    <property name="dataSource" ref="jobRepository-dataSource" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jobRepository-transactionManager" />
    <property name="databaseType" value="mysql" />
    <property name="isolationLevelForCreate" value="ISOLATION_DEFAULT" />
    <property name="tablePrefix" value="batch_" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobExplorer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="jobRepository-dataSource" p:tablePrefix="batch_"  />

<bean id="jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean id="jobRegistry" class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />

<bean id="jobOperator" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    <property name="jobLauncher" ref="jobLauncher" />
    <property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
    <property name="jobExplorer" ref="jobExplorer" />
</bean>
```